# Can I benefit from React's virtual DOM and How to make <path> transition animation

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

All:

I am pretty new React, what I want to build is a line chart.

If I **use D3**, it basically use:

```
var lines = linechart.selectAll("path").data(arrayOfDatasetForAllLines);
lines.enter().append("path")
lines.transition.duration(800).attr("d", function(d, i){return linebuilder(d);})
```

If I use React, it probably like:

```
<g>
    { arrayOfDatasetForAllLines.map((d, i)=>{
            var pathdata = linebuilder(d)
            return <path d={pathdata} />
        })
    }
</g>
```

There are two questions I have here:

1. How much I can benefit from React's virtual DOM in this use case compared with D3 way, **especially when the number of lines does not change** but only the data set of each line changes?
2. Forget the benefit, say if I decide to use React for this, how do I **achieve that .transition().duration() in React way**?